# How can I import this file, in SAS, without error?

Tags: sas

I'm trying to import a file, with this code I receive the error message:

> The table "WORK.HOTDOGS" cannot be opened because it does not contain
>   any columns.

Here is the code:

```
/* Import file, Print Data Table, Plot bar chart of Type vs Type Frequency */

DATA HotDogs;
    INFILE '/folders/myfolders/hot_dogs.sas7bdat';
RUN;

PROC PRINT DATA=HotDogs;
RUN;
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Here is a link to the data file: http://support.sas.com/learn/statlibrary/statlib_eg4.2/xData.htm#hot_dogs

Comment: SET statement, not INFILE statement, for reading a SAS dataset.

Comment: You might find the video tutorials helpful: https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLVBcK_IpFVi9cajJtRel2uBLbtcLz-WIN

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify a library that refers to your SAS data set and/or use a SET statement. Since it looks like you're using SAS UE here's a link to their video tutorials on youtube.
https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLVBcK_IpFVi9cajJtRel2uBLbtcLz-WIN

```
libname mydata '/folders/myfolders/';

data hotdogs;
set mydata.hot_dogs;
run;
```

OR

```
data hotdogs;
set '/folder/myfolders/hot_dogs.sas7bdat';
run;
```

Comment: Unfortunately I think I'm not setting my folders up correctly, could be a problem with my virtual machine software, (VMware). Given up on it until I start my new job and get a different version of SAS to work with.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. It needs to be imported as follows:

```
data work.hotdogs;
     INFILE '/folders/myfolders/hot_dogs.sas7bdat';
     input make $ Model;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in the SAS UE, solved it by deleting the dataset and re-uploading it. Somehow worked.